# What are some different ways to do a for loop in Julia 1.0+?

Tags: julia

I am looking for different ways of writing for loops in Julia! I know this is a basic question but I'm wondering what some of the different options are and if there are advantages/disadvantages with respect to performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For loop

Pro: fully flexible has break and continue

Con: no return, must specify iterator at start

#### While loop

Pro: fully flexible has break and continue

Con: no return, if iterator must be handled manually

#### Label+goto

Please don't use this for loops

#### Generator comprehension/Vector comprehension

Pro: Has return value, continue is expressed with filter clause, comes in lazy (generator) and eager forms (vector), can create multidimensional return vale

Con: really ugly for anything long, no break

#### Broadcast

Pro: express transform of multiple input susictly, has return value with output structure matching what it should be. Can be expressed with just a dot and supports loop fusion.

Con: no break no contine. Writing body means writing a function. Wrapping things you want to broadcast as scalar in  `Ref` is a bit ugly

#### Map/pmap/asyncmap

Written in do-block form

Pro: can easily change to run distributed or asynchronously, had a return value

Con: no break, no continue

#### `foreach` function

It is a lot like map but no return value. So save on allocating that.

Other than that same pros and cons

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from the [Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/index.html#man-loops-1):

The for loop makes common repeated evaluation idioms easier to write. Since counting up and down like the above while loop does is so common, it can be expressed more concisely with a for loop:

```
julia> for i = 1:5
           println(i)
       end
1
2
3
4
5
```

Here the `1:5` is a range object, representing the sequence of numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. The for loop iterates through these values, assigning each one in turn to the variable i. One rather important distinction between the previous while loop form and the for loop form is the scope during which the variable is visible. If the variable `i` has not been introduced in another scope, in the for loop form, it is visible only inside of the for loop, and not outside/afterward. You'll either need a new interactive session instance or a different variable name to test this:

```
julia> for j = 1:5
           println(j)
       end
1
2
3
4
5

julia> j
ERROR: UndefVarError: j not defined
```

See [Scope of Variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#scope-of-variables-1) for a detailed explanation of the variable scope and how it works in Julia.

In general, the for loop construct can iterate over any container. In these cases, the alternative (but fully equivalent) keyword `in` or `∈` is typically used instead of `=`, since it makes the code read more clearly:

```
julia> for i in [1,4,0]
           println(i)
       end
1
4
0

julia> for s ∈ ["foo","bar","baz"]
           println(s)
       end
foo
bar
baz
```

Various types of iterable containers will be introduced and discussed in later sections of the manual (see, e.g., [Multi-dimensional Arrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-multi-dim-arrays-1)).